# SQL to find time elapsed from multiple overlapping intervals

Tags: sql, intervals, gaps-and-islands

Not using MSSQL or DB2 or Oracle. 
No CTE. 
No OVERLAP predicate. 
No INTERVAL data type. 
The situation: on a vehicle to be repaired work can not start until
all parts ordered for the job have been received.
Parts may be ordered multiple times prior to the start of repair.
We need to extract the time for which the vehicle was on "parts hold"

So for a vehicle identified as id = 1
parts were ordered (d1) and received (d2) on 4 different occasions

```
    ID     d1     d2
     1     8/1    8/8
     1     8/2    8/6
     1     8/12   8/14
     1     8/3    8/10

 8/1                             8/8
  d1                              d2   
  |-------------------------------|  
         8/2             8/6                    8/12      8/14                  
         d1               d2                     d1        d2     
          |---------------|                      |----------|    
                   8/3                 8/10
                   d1                    d2
                   |---------------------|   
 8/1                                                       8/14
  |---------------------------------------------------------|  = 13 days
                                        8/10    8/12
  |--------------------------------------|    +  |----------|  = parts hold  = 11 days
```

As seen from above, the wait time to start work (assuming 8/1 as the
date from which the vehicle was available for work) was 13 days.
The actual time spent waiting for parts was 11 days, which is the number
we need to derive from the data.
The actual datetime data will be timestamps from which we will extract hours,
we used dates in this sample data for simplicity of presentation.
We are struggling to generate a set (not psm, not udf, not cursor) based solution.
TIA

Comment: I's have though a left join on an auxiliary calendar table might help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a good way to find gaps in a set of datespans?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765495/what-is-a-good-way-to-find-gaps-in-a-set-of-datespans)

Comment: @Brian, this question is much different. OP, are you able to add a view(s) to assist in the query?

Comment: If you look at your example "drawing" you could try a solution that would count the number of undelivered orders per date. 8/1-8/2 = 2, 8/2-8/3 = 3, 8/3-8/6 = 4 and so on. When you get to 8/10-8/12 you have 0 outstanding deliveries. Count the dates with a non-zero value and you gave the wait days.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This SQL statement seems to get what you want (t is the table name of the sampe table):

```
SELECT
   d.id, 
   d.duration, 
   d.duration - 
   IFNULL(
      ( SELECT Sum( timestampdiff( SQL_TSI_DAY, 
                                   no_hold.d2, 
                                   ( SELECT min(d1) FROM t t4 
                                     WHERE t4.id = no_hold.id and t4.d1 > no_hold.d2 )))
        FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT id, d2 FROM t t1 
               WHERE ( SELECT sum( IIF( t1.d2 between t2.d1 and t2.d2, 1, 0 ) ) 
                       FROM t t2 WHERE t2.id = t1.id and t2.d2 <> t1.d2 ) = 0 
             And d2 <> ( select max( d2 ) from t t3 where t3.id = t1.id )) no_hold
        WHERE no_hold.id = d.id ),
      0 ) "parts hold"
FROM 
   ( SELECT id, timestampdiff( SQL_TSI_DAY, min( d1 ), max( d2 ) ) duration
     FROM t GROUP BY id ) d
```

The outer query gets the duration of the repair work. The complex subquery calculates the total number of days not waiting for parts. This is done by locating the start dates where the vehicle is not waiting for parts, and then count the number of days until it begins to wait for parts again:

```
// 1) The query for finding the starting dates when the vehicle is not waiting for parts, 
// i.e. finding all d2 that is not within any date range where the vehicle is waiting for part.
// The DISTINCT is needed to removed duplicate starting "no hold" period.

SELECT DISTINCT id, d2 
FROM t t1
WHERE ( SELECT sum( IIF( t1.d2 between t2.d1 and t2.d2, 1, 0 ) ) from t t2 
        WHERE t2.id = t1.id and t2.d2 <> t1.d2 ) = 0 AND 
      d2 <> ( SELECT max( d2 ) FROM t t3 WHERE t3.id = t1.id ) )
```

// 2) The days where it vehicle is not waiting for part is the date from the above query till the vehicle is // waiting for part again

```
timestampdiff( SQL_TSI_DAY, no_hold.d2, ( SELECT min(d1) FROM t t4 WHERE t4.id = no_hold.id and t4.d1 > no_hold.d2 ) )
```

Combining the two above and aggregating all such periods gives the number of days that the vehicle is not waiting for parts. The final query adds an extra condition to calculate result for each id from the outer query.

This probably is not terribly efficient on very large table with many ids. It should fine if the id is limited to one or just a few.

Comment: Edited to fix problem with duplicate starting date of "no hold" periods.

Comment: Alex: in the main code block above, missing a right paren after

Comment: after: And d2 <> ( select max( d2 ) from t t3 where t3.id = t1.id )

Answer (score 8):

I couldn't get @Alex W's queries to work. It is not standard SQL, so it required a lot of rewrite to be compatible with SQL Server (which I can test). But it did give me some inspiration, which I have expanded upon.

---

Find all start-points of every period of uninterrupted waiting:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    t1.ID,
    t1.d1 AS date,
    -DATEDIFF(DAY, (SELECT MIN(d1) FROM Orders), t1.d1) AS n
FROM Orders t1
LEFT JOIN Orders t2                   -- Join for any events occurring while this
    ON t2.ID = t1.ID                  -- is starting. If this is a start point,
    AND t2.d1 <> t1.d1                -- it won't match anything, which is what
    AND t1.d1 BETWEEN t2.d1 AND t2.d2 -- we want.
GROUP BY t1.ID, t1.d1, t1.d2
HAVING COUNT(t2.ID) = 0
```

And the equivalent for end-points:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    t1.ID,
    t1.d2 AS date,
    DATEDIFF(DAY, (SELECT MIN(d1) FROM Orders), t1.d2) AS n
FROM Orders t1
LEFT JOIN Orders t2
    ON t2.ID = t1.ID
    AND t2.d2 <> t1.d2
    AND t1.d2 BETWEEN t2.d1 AND t2.d2
GROUP BY t1.ID, t1.d1, t1.d2
HAVING COUNT(t2.ID) = 0
```

`n` is the number of days since some common point in time. Start-points have a negative value, and end-points have a positive value. This is so that we can just add them up to get the number of days in between.

```
span = end - start
span = end + (-start)
span1 + span2 = end1 + (-start1) + end2 + (-start2)
```

Finally, we just need to add things up:

```
SELECT ID, SUM(n) AS hold_days
FROM (
   SELECT DISTINCT
       t1.id,
       t1.d1 AS date,
       -DATEDIFF(DAY, (SELECT MIN(d1) FROM Orders), t1.d1)  AS n
   FROM Orders t1
   LEFT JOIN Orders t2
      ON t2.ID = t1.ID
      AND t2.d1 <> t1.d1
      AND t1.d1 BETWEEN t2.d1 AND t2.d2
   GROUP BY t1.ID, t1.d1, t1.d2
   HAVING COUNT(t2.ID) = 0
   UNION ALL
   SELECT DISTINCT
       t1.id,
       t1.d2 AS date,
       DATEDIFF(DAY, (SELECT MIN(d1) FROM Orders), t1.d2) AS n
   FROM Orders t1
   LEFT JOIN Orders t2
      ON t2.ID = t1.ID
      AND t2.d2 <> t1.d2
      AND t1.d2 BETWEEN t2.d1 AND t2.d2
   GROUP BY t1.ID, t1.d1, t1.d2
   HAVING COUNT(t2.ID) = 0
   ORDER BY ID, date
) s
GROUP BY ID;
```

Input table (Orders):

```
ID   d1           d2
 1   2011-08-01   2011-08-08
 1   2011-08-02   2011-08-06
 1   2011-08-03   2011-08-10
 1   2011-08-12   2011-08-14
 2   2011-08-01   2011-08-03
 2   2011-08-02   2011-08-06
 2   2011-08-05   2011-08-09
```

Output:

```
ID   hold_days
 1          11
 2           8
```

---

Alternatively, you can do this with a stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CalculateHoldTimes
    @ID int = 0
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE Events CURSOR FOR
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT d1 AS date, 1 AS diff
        FROM Orders
        WHERE ID = @ID
        UNION ALL
        SELECT d2 AS date, -1 AS diff
        FROM Orders
        WHERE ID = @ID
    ) s
    ORDER BY date;

    DECLARE @Events_date date,
            @Events_diff int,
            @Period_start date,
            @Period_accum int,
            @Total_start date,
            @Total_count int;

    OPEN Events;

    FETCH NEXT FROM Events
    INTO @Events_date, @Events_diff;

    SET @Period_start = @Events_date;
    SET @Period_accum = 0;
    SET @Total_start = @Events_date;
    SET @Total_count = 0;

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @Period_accum = @Period_accum + @Events_diff;

        IF @Period_accum = 1 AND @Events_diff = 1
            -- Start of period
            SET @Period_start = @Events_date;
        ELSE IF @Period_accum = 0 AND @Events_diff = -1
            -- End of period
            SET @Total_count = @Total_count +
                DATEDIFF(day, @Period_start, @Events_date);

        FETCH NEXT FROM Events
        INTO @Events_date, @Events_diff;
    END;

    SELECT
        @Total_start AS d1,
        @Events_date AS d2,
        @Total_count AS hold_time;
END;
```

Call it with:

```
EXEC CalculateHoldTimes 1;
```

Comment: Thank you MizardX, this is exactly what we were looking for

Comment: Now you can. :) Anyway; You can still accept an answer if you think it answers your question. Click on the check-mark below the voting arrows.

Comment: MizardX:  the dialect of SQL in Alex's response is that used by Sybase Advantage, which is the product we use, hence my joy at his response

Comment: @MarkusJarderot I have some up questions if you have a moment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48531322/sql-counting-days-with-gap-overlapping?noredirect=1#comment84058272_48531322

Answer (score 0):

```
USE [DnnMasterShoraSystem]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[CalculateHoldTimes]    Script Date: 12/8/2014 1:36:12 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CalculateHoldTimes]
    @PID int    
AS
BEGIN      
CREATE TABLE #tblTemp(
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [BID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Active] [bit] NULL,
    [WorkStartDate] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [WorkEndDate] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [jobStateID] [int] NULL,
    [RegisterType] [int] NULL,
    [RegisterState] [int] NULL,
    [En_time] [datetime] NULL,
    [Fa_time] [nvarchar](40) NULL,
    [Status] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [PortalId] [int] NULL,
    [ModuleId] [int] NULL,
    [UserId] [int] NULL,
    [BrName] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
    [BrCode] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [WorkEndDate_New] [nvarchar](10) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

insert into #tblTemp
select * from [dbo].[Shora.Personel_Branch_Copy] 
        where WorkStartDate is not null 
        --and [dbo].[ShamsiToMiladi](WorkStartDate) <GETDATE() 
        --and [dbo].[ShamsiToMiladi](WorkEndDate) <GETDATE() 
        and PID=@PID
        --and [dbo].[ShamsiToMiladi](WorkEndDate)<[dbo].[ShamsiToMiladi](@NewDate)
        order by WorkStartDate

DECLARE Events CURSOR FOR
    SELECT [dbo].[ShamsiToMiladi](WorkStartDate) AS StartDate,[dbo].[ShamsiToMiladi](WorkEndDate) AS EndDate
        FROM #tblTemp        
    ORDER BY StartDate;

--drop table #tblTemp

    DECLARE @SDate date,
            @EDate date,
            @Period_Start date,
            @Period_End date,
            @Total int,
            @OldSDate date,
            @OldEDate date


    OPEN Events;

    FETCH NEXT FROM Events
    INTO @SDate, @EDate;

    set @Total=0
    SET @Period_Start =@SDate
    set @Period_End=@EDate

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN      
    if @OldSDate>@Period_End
        begin
            set @Period_Start=@SDate            

            if @Period_End>=@Period_Start
            set @Total+=DATEDIFF(DAY,@Period_Start,@Period_End)
        end
    else if @SDate<@Period_End
        begin       
        set @Period_Start=@Period_Start     
            set @Total=DATEDIFF(DAY,@Period_Start,@Period_End)
        end

        set @OldSDate=@SDate 
        set @OldEDate=@EDate

        FETCH NEXT FROM Events
        INTO @SDate, @EDate;

        if  @Period_End<@EDate
        set @Period_End=@EDate

    END;

INSERT INTO [dbo].[PersonelDays]
           (PID
           ,[Total_Start]
           ,[Total_End]
           ,[Total_count])
     VALUES
           (@PID,           
            @Period_Start,
            @Period_End,
            @Total
           )

drop table #tblTemp
CLOSE Events
DEALLOCATE Events
END;
```